# Why does it keep loading forever?

Tags: flutter, dart

there is a problem. I have SOMETIMES no download icon disappears. Or to put it another way, instead of "No more entries", I see a loading circle.

This happens depending on how much data I received. For example, for 5 records there will be an endless download, and for 6 records it will display "There are no more records"

Tell me, what's the problem?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var ressultat = json.decode(MyApp.resultat)['Transactions'];
  final controller = ScrollController();
  bool hasMore = true;
  int page = 2;
  bool isLoading = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // fetch();
    controller.addListener(() {
      if(controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
        fetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future fetch() async {
    if(isLoading) return;
    isLoading = true;

    var token = LoginClass.resJson;
    const limit = 9;

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Config.urlReport),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
          },
          body: json.encode({
            "Filters": {
              "DateFrom" : MyApp.dateFrom,
              "DateTo" : MyApp.dateEnd,
              "AmountFrom": MyApp.sumFrom,
              "AmountTo": MyApp.sumTo,
              "SenderPaymentSystemId": MyApp.dropdownvalue,
              "SenderRequisite": MyApp.phoneNum},
            "Sorting": {
              "Field": MyApp.isCheckedFieldPicker,
              "Order": MyApp.isCheckedOrderPicker},
            "Pagination": {
              "PageNumber": page,
              "PageSize": limit
            }
          })
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var reportResult = (response.body);
        print(reportResult);
        final List ress = json.decode(reportResult)['Transactions'];
        setState(() {
          page++;
          isLoading = false;
          if(MyApp.rowNumber!.length < limit) {
            hasMore = false;
          }

          MyApp.rowNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final rowNumber = item['RowNumber'].toString();
            return rowNumber;
          }));
          MyApp.walletName?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final walletName = item['WalletName'].toString();
            return walletName;
          }));
          MyApp.payerPhoneNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final phoneNumber = item['SenderRequisite'].toString();
            return phoneNumber;
          }));
          MyApp.createdDate?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final createdDate = item['CreatedDate'].toString();
            return createdDate;
          }));
          MyApp.amount?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final amount = item['Amount'].toString();
            return amount;
          }));
        });



        print(MyApp.createdDate.runtimeType);
      } else {
        var res = response.statusCode;
        print(res);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

  }
```

Here is all the necessary code, if you need something else, please let me know

```
  child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: controller,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            itemCount: MyApp.rowNumber!.length + 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (index < MyApp.rowNumber!.length)  {
                                 return Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                            children: [
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Text(' ${MyApp.rowNumber?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    width: 80,
                                                    child:  Text('${MyApp.createdDate?[index].replaceFirst(RegExp('T'), '')}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text('${MyApp.walletName?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                        Text('${MyApp.payerPhoneNumber?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Text('${MyApp.amount?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )

                                );
                              } else {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: hasMore
                                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                        : const Text('Список полностью загружен')
                                  ,),
                                );
                              }

                            }
                        )
```

UPD: I clarify the question: My first request was sent with a limit of 9 entries, however, if there are less than 9 entries, then there will be an endless download. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't see your build method.  Is `fetch` being called directly from build()?  If so, there's your problem, since build() can be called 60 times per second.

Comment: i'm calling it here - is that right?
`@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // fetch();
    controller.addListener(() {
      if(controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
        fetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override`

Comment: you are not setting isLoading as false for HTTP request's response other than 200 and for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not setting isLoading as false for HTTP request's response other than 200 and for error.

```
Future fetch() async {
if(isLoading) return;
isLoading = true;

var token = LoginClass.resJson;
const limit = 9;

try {
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(Config.urlReport),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "Filters": {
          "DateFrom" : MyApp.dateFrom,
          "DateTo" : MyApp.dateEnd,
          "AmountFrom": MyApp.sumFrom,
          "AmountTo": MyApp.sumTo,
          "SenderPaymentSystemId": MyApp.dropdownvalue,
          "SenderRequisite": MyApp.phoneNum},
        "Sorting": {
          "Field": MyApp.isCheckedFieldPicker,
          "Order": MyApp.isCheckedOrderPicker},
        "Pagination": {
          "PageNumber": page,
          "PageSize": limit
        }
      })
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var reportResult = (response.body);
    print(reportResult);
    final List ress = json.decode(reportResult)['Transactions'];
    setState(() {
      page++;
      isLoading = false;
      if(MyApp.rowNumber!.length < limit) {
        hasMore = false;
      }

      MyApp.rowNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
        final rowNumber = item['RowNumber'].toString();
        return rowNumber;
      }));
      MyApp.walletName?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
        final walletName = item['WalletName'].toString();
        return walletName;
      }));
      MyApp.payerPhoneNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
        final phoneNumber = item['SenderRequisite'].toString();
        return phoneNumber;
      }));
      MyApp.createdDate?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
        final createdDate = item['CreatedDate'].toString();
        return createdDate;
      }));
      MyApp.amount?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
        final amount = item['Amount'].toString();
        return amount;
      }));
    });
    print(MyApp.createdDate.runtimeType);
  } else {
    var res = response.statusCode;
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
    print(res);
  }
} catch (error) {
  isLoading = false;
  setState(() {});
  print(error);
}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem.
After all, I send the first request from another page, respectively, if all records are unloaded at once (they are less than the limit), then the request does not occur and, accordingly, so that I do not write in the exception, there will be no sense ((

But thanks for the answer, I added it, it will not be superfluous

Comment: it seems you also have another variable hasMore which decides the to show loader or text. Kindly set that to false in respective places and try again. The boolean variable is set to true on page initialization itself. As per condition, if your data is less than 9, you will have the text and if your data is more than 9, you will have loading indicator infintely.